# How to access Cinemachine Basic MutliChannel Perlin Noise?

Tags: unity-game-engine

how can I access the component of the "CinemachineFreeLook Camera's CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin' for me to change some variables in the C#?
Like changing the Amplitude Gain or Frequency Gain

Comment: Via [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) (or any of its similar versions like `GetComponentInChildren`) or via [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) like usual for any other components in Unity?

Comment: GetComponentInChildren worked for me to access its cinemachinebasicmultichannel perlin noise of cinemachine free look.GetComponent didn't work and the findobjectoftype, it keeps getting null

Comment: If `GetComponentInChildren` works then also `GetComponent` would work if used on the correct object .. if your component is inactive or your gameObject disabled then `FindObjectOfType` doesn't find it .. but neither does `GetComponentInChildren` except you pass in `true` as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the CinemachineVirtualCamera script, I understand that the components of the virtual cameras are attached on a hidden child gameobject

```cs
/// <summary>This is the name of the hidden GameObject that will be created as a child object
/// of the virtual camera.  This hidden game object acts as a container for the polymorphic
/// CinemachineComponent pipeline.  The Inspector UI for the Virtual Camera
/// provides access to this pipleline, as do the CinemachineComponent-family of
/// public methods in this class.
/// The lifecycle of the pipeline GameObject is managed automatically.</summary>
public const string PipelineName = "cm";
```

So I suggest you to get the component like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class YourScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private CinemachineVirtualCamera m_vcam = null; 

    [System.NonSerialized]
    private CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin m_noiseComp = null;

    void Start()
    {
        m_noiseComp = m_vcam.GetComponentInChildren<CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin>();
        if(noiseComp == null)
            Debug.LogError("No MultiChannelPerlin on the virtual camera.", this);
        else
            Debug.Log($"Noise Component: {noiseComp}");
    }
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! AAAAAAAA THANK YOUUUUUU VERY MUCH!!!!!!! I WAS JUST LOOKING FOR SOME RIGHT SYNTAX OF ACCESSING THE CINEMACHINEBASICMULT OF FREELOOK FOR HOURS AND THINKING OVER AND OVER AGAIN HAHAHAHA GOODD THING I FOUND YOUR SYNTAX WHICH IS THIS : GetComponentInChildren<CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin>() 
IT WORKED PERFECTLY.. BECAUSE PEOPLE USUALLY USED GetCinemachineCompopnent which didn't work for me and kept thinking of what am i doing wrong and looking for the right syntax of it. thank youuuuuuuuuuuuu